# Problem with orientation while extruding

Tags: extrude

Whenever I try to extrude the extrusion doesn't happen the normal way. I guess it is happening along the normal. It is making it very hard for me to make stuff like the handles of a coffee cup.
[image]

Also, this blue line appears and the extrusion goes along the line until I press X, Y, or Z which also messed up the face making the extrusion look very bad.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: when you extrude, by default it will extrude along the face normals. If you press X, Y or Z it will extrude along the global axis, if you press XX, YY or ZZ it will extrude along the object axis. How would you like it to work?

Comment: what is "not normal" way to you? Because yes this is default extrude that follows normal because you are extruding face along normal, the blue line is face normal Z axis that extrusion follows